# Taskbar icon for Windows 10 app with VS tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: windows, cordova, icons, visual-studio-cordova, taskbar

I want to target Windows 10 with VS (2015) tools for Apache Cordova.

I seem unable to set the taskbar icon.

I've swapped all the icons that were preset by Visual Studio:

```
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" height="44" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" height="71" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
```

Since this did not make any difference (I have cleaned the solution many times), I've checked the guide by MS itself on [configuring the app assets](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-app/). I then have added also these assets:

```
<icon src="res/icons/windows/logo.png" width="150" height="150" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/smalllogo.png" width="30" height="30" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/storelogo.png" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/splashscreen.png" width="620" height="300" />
```

Nevertheless, I still get the default "no icon" image (an X).

Comment: Have you changed the "Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" icon? This is the default task bar icon.

Comment: I can't believe I've spent so much time on this.. I had written a script to generate all the images and I did not notice that for some resources I was generating jpg files, including `Square44x44Logo.scale-100.JPG`. Thus the wrong reference...